# Is Hystrix able to open a circuit depending on method parameters?

Tags: java, hystrix, circuit-breaker

If I have the following Hystrix command:

```java
public class TimeoutDependingOnParam extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private final String name;

    public TimeoutDependingOnParam (String name) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"));
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() {

        if (name.equals("Looong")) {
           waitABillionYears();
        }

        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

called by:

```java
// no timeout for "Quick"
String s1 = new TimeoutDependingOnParam("Quick").execute();

// timeout for "Looong"
String s2 = new TimeoutDependingOnParam("Looong").execute();
```

If Hystrix opens the circuit because the call with "Looong" times out, does that mean **the call with "Quick" will be opened to** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically YES as long as both have the same command key like in your example. But for the circuit breaker to open there are more conditions [as stated in the documentation about the Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#CircuitBreaker).

You could either implement two different commands, or set the CommandKey in the constructor depending on the parameters. [This is an extract from the documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#command-name):

```
public CommandHelloWorld(String name) {
    super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"))
            .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("HelloWorld")));
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ahus, so  think I could do somethink like `publicTimeoutDependingOnParam (String name) {super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("TDPGroup")).andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("TDP" + name)));this.name = name;}`